# knockout in asp.net web from master page

Tags: asp.net, web, knockout.js, master-pages

Good day.

I was using knockout in an asp.net web form master page. On master page i have an advanced search control completely with knockout. After selecting the search criteria by readio buttons, tabs and dropdowns, on clicking a search button redirect to a details page which is also inherited from the same master page.

I need to persists the selected view from the first page in the details page along with populating the search result.

But I'm unable to do it as an infant in knockout.

I guess if I can remove the binding and apply it again, it will be happen.(don't know I'm wrong or not).

Kindly advice me to get over this situation.

Thanks

Santhi

Comment: can you post sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing a complete trip to the server between pages.  In that case you'll need to store the state of your search box somehow before the redirect, and then load that state after the redirect.  You have a couple ways to do this.

### Using Cookies

You could serialize the state of your select control into a JSON string and store it in a cookie.  When your search box loads, look for that cookie using JavaScript and if it exists, load the data into your search box.

### Using the Query String

You could serialize the state of your select control into the query string, and load from that.  This would be a little bit more reliable in case cookies are turned off on the user's browser.

### Using Local Storage

If you're working in modern browsers and supporting HTML 5, you could use HTML 5 local storage to store the search state between postbacks.  http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

### Serializing your Model State

Take a look at this page of the Knockout JS documentation for more info on serializing your object graph.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Really I was using JS global variables to maintain values, problem is I cant remove a binding in master page from child page, but i can update it and apply again. On that case binding seems twice.

Comment: @user2568288, you can apply your bindings to specific elements by sending a second param to applyBindings : ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))